# Visual Studio 2013 crashing while opening solution: Attempting to activate an adapter in state TextViewInitializing

Tags: visual-studio-2013

My system got shut down anyhow and after this I am not able to open projects in visual studio 2013. I tried creating new project and it was opening and running fine untill I added a new class library to it. Once my new solution has two project, it started creating same problem. Visual studio is not opening solution with message "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 has stopped working". I tried to debug this and getting below error:

"System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.dll

Additional information: Attempting to activate an adapter in state TextViewInitializing"

[image: Attached the screenshot]

I tried google to search the solution but not getting anything relevant. I tried clearing temp files but no success. I cleared bin and debug folder but still no luck. Do you have any solution for this.

Comment: Pretty safe to assume your machine is broken, tends to be what goes wrong next when a machine shuts down unexpectedly for no discernable reason.  You'll have to spin the repair/reinstall wheel of fortune, after performing basic machine health tests.  Use superuser.com for advice.

Comment: @HansPassant Then why it working fine when I have only one project in my solution. Any idea?

Comment: Well I tried repairing my Visual Studio and all goes well now.